# Limit max number of connections coming from a specific IP address

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I want to limit the number of connections of a specific IP (147.0.0.0 for example) to 25 concurrent connections for the port 5566.

I am currently able to limit the max concurrent connections of the whole port and for all the IP addresses... but I want to do it for (147.0.0.0) only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--connlimit-above` option for the `connlimit` module should achieve your objective. See also [the man pages for iptables-extenstions](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html). Example, assuming tcp:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -s 147.0.0.0 --dport 5566 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 25 -j REJECT
```

Resulting in:

```
~$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 432 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       147.0.0.0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5566 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn src/32 > 25 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 624 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```